# Live username Checking is not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, live

I am trying to make register page with jquery and php where user put his username and while he is inserting in text box his username, my website check immediately if it is available or not and show! But my code is not working.
Here is my js code :

```
$(".r74re").keyup(function (e){
        var user_name = $(this).val();
        if(user_name.length >= 4)
        $.post('liveusername.php', {'username':user_name}, function(data) {
                $('.step1 input.usrname:focus').css({               
                    'background': '#fff url("images/loader.gif") 275px no-repeat',
                    'background-size':'10px 20px'
                }); 
                setTimeout(function (){
                  if(data.success){
                     console.log("in positive " + data);
                     $('.step1 input.usrname:focus').css({              
                        'background-color': 'lightgreen',
                        'background-size':''
                    });     
                  }else{
                    console.log("in negative  " + data);
                    $('.step1 input.usrname:focus').css({               
                        'background-color': 'red',
                        'background-size':''
                    });                     
                  }           
                }, 1000);


            });
```

Here is my php code that `$.Post` call when keyup event is :

```
include ("dbcon.php");
include ("funchuge.php");

if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }
    //sleep(1);// for animating
    if(strlen($_POST["username"]) > 3){
        selfValidator($_POST["username"]);
        $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); 
        $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:usname");
        $statement->bindparam(':usname', $username);
        $statement->execute();
        if($statement->fetch()){
            $message = "ItExists";
            echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'messages' => $message]);

        }else{

            $message = "NotExists";
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'messages' => $message]);

        }
    }
}
```

I test  a lot and i found problem in js code in line `if(data.success)` this condition is not working.. it always show me else condition if user allso exists.. i dont know why happening this ? Someone can help me found out my problem.

Comment: i am new in computer science, i dont have good experince to asking a good question, i am already in danger zone, i hope i explain my question nice.

Comment: Try to output `data`, not `data.success`.

Comment: @Script47 - He needs to use `data.success`, but `data` is a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the returned PHP string into JSON before you can access it like an object. Add this line above your `setTimeout`.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: hey boss, its working. but one more question. parse won't create any problem for attack ? if someone can inject parse ???

Comment: Nope, `parse` is user-facing & client-side, so nothing is going back to your data.